# How much does my volume group use of my hard drive?

Tags: linux, lvm, hard-disk

I want to know how much space of my hard drive is being used in the hard drive , let me explain:

My first hard drive is `/dev/sda` and the second one is `/dev/sdb` each one of them has a logical voume and they are in the same volume group, i can easily know how much of this volume group is used , but how much of each drive is used ? how does the lvm spread data across those volumes ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pvs` to show all the segments in your physical volumes and the logical volumes they contain, which will allow you to get a good idea of how your devices are used:

```
 sudo pvs --segments -o +lv_name
```

This will show something like

```
   PV         VG              Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Start  SSize  LV
  /dev/sda1  vg-fast         lvm2 a--  119.24g  23.24g      0  16384 root                
  /dev/sda1  vg-fast         lvm2 a--  119.24g  23.24g  16384   4096                     
  /dev/sda1  vg-fast         lvm2 a--  119.24g  23.24g  20480   8192 usrlocal            
  /dev/sda1  vg-fast         lvm2 a--  119.24g  23.24g  28672   1853
```

which shows that my `/dev/sda1` PV, which is part of the `vg-fast` VG, is split into four segments, two of which are unused, and two of which are used respectively for the LVs `root` and `usrlocal`.